# Fetching unicode data from PostgreSQL Erlang

Tags: postgresql, unicode, erlang, ejabberd

I'm trying to fetch data from PostgreSQL with Erlang. 
Here's my code that gets data from DB. However i have cyrrilic data in 'status' column. This cyrrilic data is not being fetched correctly.
I tried using `UserInfo = io_lib:format("~tp ~n",[UserInfoQuery]),` however this doesn't seem to work, because it crashes the app.

```
UserInfoQuery = odbc_queries:get_user_info(LServer,LUser),
UserInfo = io_lib:format("~p",[UserInfoQuery]),
?DEBUG("UserInfo: ~p",[UserInfo]),
StringForUserInfo = lists:flatten(UserInfo),

get_user_info(LServer, Id) ->
ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(
  LServer,
  [<<"select * from users "
     "where email_hash='">>, Id, "';"]).
```

Here's the data that is fetched from DB

```
{selected,[<<"username">>,<<"password">>,<<"created_at">>,
           <<"id">>,<<"email_hash">>,<<"status">>],
          [{<<"admin">>,<<"admin">>,<<"2014-05-13 12:40:30.757433">>,
            <<"1">>,<<"adminhash">>,
            <<209,139,209,132,208,178,208,176,209,139,209,132,208,
              178,208,176>>}]}
```

Question:

1. How can i extract data from column? For example only data from
   'status' column?
2. How can i extract data in unicode from DB? Should i fetch the data from DB then use
   io_lib:format("~tp~n") on it? Is there any better way to do it?

Additional question: is there any way to get string in human readable format, so that `StringForUserInfo = 'ыфваыфва'` from RowUnicode?
I tried this:

```
{selected, _, [Row]} = UserInfoQuery,
RowUnicode = io_lib:format("~tp~n", [Row]),
?DEBUG("RowUnicode: ~p",[RowUnicode]),
StringForUserInfo = lists:flatten(RowUnicode),
```

Error:

```
bad argument in call to erlang:iolist_size([123,60,60,34,97,100,109,105,110,34,
62,62,44,60,60,34,97,100,109,105,110,34,62,62,44,60,60,34,50,...])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erlang ODBC driver perfectly fetched the status column from your database. Indeed, PostgreSQL encodes your data is UTF-8, and the value you get is UTF-8 encoded.

```
Status = <<209,139,209,132,208,178,208,176,209,139,209,132,208,178,208,176>>.
```

This is a binary representing the string `ыфваыфва` in UTF-8.
You can directly use UTF-8 encoded binaries in your code. If you want to use unicode character points instead of UTF-8 bytes, you can convert this to a list of integers (a string in Erlang parlance). Just use `unicode:characters_to_list/1`, which in your case will yield list `[1099,1092,1074,1072,1099,1092,1074,1072]`. This is a list representation of the same string. Unicode character 1099 (16#044B in hex) is ы (CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YERU, cf [Cyrillic excerpt unicode chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf)).

Erlang can handle unicode texts in the two representations above: lists of unicode characters as integers and binaries of UTF-8 encoded characters.

Let's examine a smaller example, string `"ы"`. This string is composed of unicode character 044B CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YERU, and it can be encoded as a binary as `<<209,139>>` or as a list as `[16#044B]` (= `[1099]`).

Historically, lists of integers as well as binaries were Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) encoded. Unicode and ISO-8859-1 have the same values from 0 to 255, but UTF-8 transformation only matches ISO-8859-1 for characters in the 0-127 range. For this reason, Erlang's `~s` format argument has a unicode translation modifier, `~ts`. The following line will not work as expected:

```
io:format("~s", [<<209,139>>]).
```

It will output two characters, 00D1 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE) and 008B (PARTIAL LINE FORWARD). This is because <<209,139>> is interpreted as a Latin-1 string and not as a UTF-8 encoded string.

The following line will fail:

```
io:format("~s", [[1099]]).
```

This is because [1099] is not a valid Latin-1 string.

Instead, you should write:

```
io:format("~ts", [<<209,139>>]),
io:format("~ts", [[1099]]).
```

Erlang's `~p` format argument also has a unicode translation modifier, `~tp`. However, `~tp` will not do what you are looking for *alone*. Whether you use `~p` or `~tp`, by default, `io_lib:format/2` will format the Status UTF-8 encoded binary above as:

```
<<209,139,209,132,208,178,208,176,209,139,209,132,208,178,208,176>>
```

Indeed, `t` modifier only means the argument shall accept unicode input. If you do use `~p`, when formatting a string or a binary, Erlang will determine whether this could be represented as a Latin-1 string since input may be Latin-1 encoded. This heuristic allows Erlang to properly distinguish lists of integers and strings, most of the time. To see the heuristic at work, you can try something like:

```
io:format("~p\n~p\n", [[69,114,108,97,110,103], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]).
```

The heuristic detects that `[69,114,108,97,110,103]` actually is `"Erlang"`, while `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` is just, well, a list of integers.

If you do use `~tp`, Erlang will expect strings or binaries to be unicode-encoded, and then apply the **default** identification heuristic. And default heuristic happens to currently (R17) be latin-1 as well. Since your string cannot be represented with Latin-1, Erlang will display it as a list of integers. Fortunately, you can switch to Unicode heuristics by passing `+pc unicode` to Erlang on command line, and this will produce what you are looking for.

```
$ erl +pc unicode
```

So a solution to your problem is to pass `+pc unicode` and to use `~tp`.

Comment: Is there any way for me to process that data to human-readable UTF-8, and put it to Erlang string?

Comment: This data already is in UTF-8 format, and I do not understand "human-readable UTF-8". Are you looking to input UTF-8 strings in source code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why `io:format("~tp")` doesn't work, but you can extract the row and column you need and print that with `io:format("~ts")`:

```
> {selected, _, [Row]} = UserInfoQuery.
> io:format("~ts~n", [element(6, Row)]).
ыфваыфва
ok
```